# Vue.js should the main.js file be tested?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js

Performing unit test on components is fine... however running coverage , I can see that's some lines of code in the `main.js` file are not covered ...
Should the `main.js` file be tested too ?

all Vue related lines of code like :

```
  Vue.use(VeeValidate, {..
  Vue.use(Vuetify, { ..
  Vue.config.productionTip = false; ..

  new Vue({
     router,
      store,
      i18n,
      render: h => h(App)
   }).$mount("#app");
```

are not covered ... 
Or should I exclude the `main.js` file from unit:testing ?

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the main file is really only doing these two things:

1. Importing libs/plugins/addons like router etc.
2. creating the main instance

I wouldn't unit test it. If anything at that level is broken, it will be discovered in e2e tests.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... I got it